# Is it possible to write a script on a server side hook on github

Tags: bash, github, git-bash

Is it possible to write my own scripts on git server hooks.If yes how can i do that i wanted to check when someone pushes to the server on which branch they are pushing just to make sure they don't push to the wrong branch.

Comment: You mean to write scripts which GitHub itself will run on its own servers?  How would they defend themselves from malice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it is not. You can use [GitHub webhook](https://developer.github.com/webhooks/), for GitHub to send [message (payload)](https://developer.github.com/webhooks/#payloads) to your server (where you can listen to said message and trigger your own script)

But nothing would be executed on a GitHub server itself, for security reason.

Comment: well I wanted to check on which branch someone is pushing. I tried to use the pre-push hook but I have to do this on everyone's local repository i wonted to do this once and then it should work for all the participants

Comment: @codeblue yes, that is why a push event webhook (https://developer.github.com/v3/activity/events/types/#pushevent) is better: it is a centralized hook which will send you a payload with the SHA of the HEAD commit on the repository (from which you can deduce the branch).