# How to save input value using javascript for later use in html

Tags: javascript, php, html

I wanted to create a website that saves an input tag's data for later use. My goal is to create a posting system where you could close the file and have the same posted input data still showing in a div element. Is this possible to do with html and javascript or do I have to use php or something else like that? Could it be done if the data was stored in a log file and then sorted through with javascript? If this only works in php is there a roundabout way of using a html or javascript? I plan to host this on GitHub and it doesn't support php.

Comment: Is there any reason you can't use a cookie? http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

Comment: There is no reason why i wouldn't use a cookie. If others go on the website, 1: would it be compatible w/ github, 2: would others have access to those same cookies, and 3: can website data be influenced by cookies (ex: a div containing information stored in a cookie)

Comment: If you want to store it in client browser, have a look at [local storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

Comment: I wouldn't want it to be stored in just client side. It would have to be server side for everybody to access it which is what i was going for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use web storage for client side only as follows:

```
localStorage.setItem("lastname", "Smith");
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("lastname");
```

see this [tutorial for web storage](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp)

## Updat1:

If you need a shared storage to access it from all clients, you have to use
[server side session](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp)

Comment: If someone else visited this website would they still be able to access the same local storage as you?

Comment: if you want a shared storage for all client you have to save it in server side, use server session

Comment: @YourEverydayCodingEnthusiast see updated answer

Comment: Would this be possible to not do this in php? I don't think GitHub supports php files.

Comment: ofcourse not, javascript runs on client browser so it's data are totally for the client browser and there's no way to share data between clients without using a server,

Comment: So in conclusion, there is no way to create a posting service using github?

Comment: using javascript no, but see this alternative way http://stackoverflow.com/a/26375622/2374987

Comment: Thanks for all of your help, I think I am going to stray away from using webhooks and payloads (seeing that I am quite new to Git) and use an alternative. Thank you though!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Cookies](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp) or HTML 5 [Local Storage](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp).

Example usage of the cookie

```
// sets the cookie cookie1
document.cookie =
 'cookie1=test; expires=Fri, 3 Aug 2001 20:47:11 UTC; path=/'

// sets the cookie cookie2 (cookie1 is *not* overwritten)
document.cookie =
 'cookie2=test; expires=Fri, 3 Aug 2001 20:47:11 UTC; path=/'

// remove cookie2
document.cookie = 'cookie2=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 UTC; path=/'
```

Example usage of  Local Storage

```
var testObject = { 'one': 1, 'two': 2, 'three': 3 };

// Put the object into storage
localStorage.setItem('testObject', JSON.stringify(testObject));

// Retrieve the object from storage
var retrievedObject = localStorage.getItem('testObject');

console.log('retrievedObject: ', JSON.parse(retrievedObject));
```

Comment: Thanks, I think that using the JSON.stringify() and JSON.parse() methods should help out with what i am trying to do.